# Ubuntu 20.04 - bad performance of Intel HD graphics 630

Tags: drivers, 20.04, graphics, intel-graphics

I have a intel hd 630 graphics card

- Ubuntu 18.04 -> no problems / fast / text on screen well readable
- Ubuntu 20.04 -> choppy performance / slow / text very small on screen

As I understand intel hd graphics drivers should be supported by both above mentioned linux versions.

lspci give me

```
VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Device 3e98
...
Kernel driver in use: i915
Kernel modules: i915
```

When I should down the computer, reconnect the display to my second GPU (Nvidia RTX), then reboot the performance on

- 20.04 is: no problems / fast / text good readable on screen

(proprietary nvidia drivers were installed via the "additional drivers" / apt interface)

I'm not sure what to do?

- Is 20.04 significantly slower than 18.04?
- Are there "better" intel hd drivers than the ones preinstalled with Ubuntu 20.04?

Context:

- I'm using a huge 35 inch ultrawidescreen monitor
- I installed all 20.04 updates (20.04.5 LTS, kernel: 5.15.0-52-generic)

Comment: It sounds like when you connect the monitor to your Intel GPU, your system still tries to use the NV card to render and redirect display to the Intel GPU via PRIME. That causes sloweness and choppiness

Comment: Could be, yes. Any idea how to fix that? (I remember installing headless Nvidia drivers on Ubuntu 18.04 because the GPU is only supposed to work for CUDA related tasks but never for serving the XServer / GUI / window manager)